# Ranked/Ordinal data - 3 variables

Tags: ordinal-data, spearman-rho

I have the following hypothesis:

- Novice drivers perceive road environments as more difficult when there are more pedestrians.

I have the following data:

- The category each driver falls in to (1. Novices, 2. Experienced, 3. Advanced)
- Number of pedestrians identified in 5 separate sections for 26 drivers
- Ranked difficulty for each section (obtained from a questionnaire from each driver)

Example:

Driver (1 Novice)
Section (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
No. of pedestrians (5, 6, 8, 25, 20)
Ranked difficulty (1, 3, 2, 5, 4)

I have ranked the number of pedestrians and compared it to the ranked difficulty in SPSS using Spearmans ranked correlation. I did this separately for each driver group. The correlation co-efficients are:

- Novice 0.57
- Experienced 0.56
- Advanced 0.77

Is this the right test or is there a better test to use to analyse the data? My advanced driver data set is also much smaller than the others, will this cause problems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a multilevel ordinal logistic regression model with difficulty as the dependent variable and number of pedestrians, skill of driver and their interaction as independent variables. You need a multilevel model to account for the non-independence of the data: Drivers may have different typical perceptions of difficulty, even within skill level.

Comment: I have carried out this ordinal regression in SPSS. However, I do not understand how to analyse the output. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Many Thanks

Comment: I don't know SPSS, but I wrote a [paper on ordinal logistic in SAS](http://www.nesug.org/Proceedings/nesug10/sa/sa03.pdf), and the output may be similar.